# Библиотека WebSocket для AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, websocket

Какую можете посоветовать хорошую библиотеку WebSocket для AS3?

К сожалению, библиотека предоставленная Worlize на githube после коннекта к серверу на PHP говорит о неправильном ключе Sec-WebSocket-Accept.

Возможно, если библиотек больше нету стоящих, то как решить подобную проблему?

Comment: Возникла еще проблемы. Библиотека Worlize ругается с такой ошибкой: "Connection Failure: There was an error while parsing the following HTTP Header line:" и не хочет работать. Хотя тест на браузере прошел успешно. С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Нужно новый вопрос создать с описанием ошибки. Приведите в нем строку заголовка, которую Worlize не может распарсить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для WebSockets в PHP есть [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)

Comment: Что-то я немного не понял как с ним обращаться и как работать в дальнейшем соединять его с Flash проектами. Не могли бы Вы немного подробнее рассказать о нем? или возможно привести какие-то руководства? (желательно на русском)

Comment: Клиент подключается и слушает сервер. Вот, например, библиотека для Flash https://github.com/Worlize/AS3WebSocket

Comment: Да нет, это я все понял. Про библиотеку тоже знаю. Мне немного не понятно как использовать Ratchet. Там как-то с помощью composer, вот именно это не понятно. Не могли бы Вы, если знаете, рассказать как использовать это (Ratchet)?

Comment: В доках Ratchet Composer упоминается, как удобный и быстрый способ установки. После того, как вы устанавливаете какую-нибудь либу с помощью Composer'а, нужно просто подключить /vendor/autoload.php Все установленные библиотеки будут загружены в проект. http://getcomposer.org/

Comment: Ну с этим я разобрался, вот только после команды "composer install" в каталоге с "composer.json" он выдает ошибку "You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https". В конфиге "extension=php_openssl.dll" раскомментировано. Других php.ini на компе не существует. Как можно исправить?

Comment: Разобрался, удалось загрузить с другой версией PHP.